# How to add NavDestination to NavigatorProvider?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation

The extension function of package androidx.navigation have plusAssign, therefore it is equivalent of `+=` but in my code it doesn't find the plusAssign.

```
class MyNavHostFragment: NavHostFragment() {
    override fun createFragmentNavigator(): Navigator<out FragmentNavigator.Destination> {
        navController.navigatorProvider += DialogFragmentNavigator(childFragmentManager)
        return super.createFragmentNavigator()
    }
}
```

©️ matpag

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please do not use screen shots for code, as they are hard to read and impossible to search.  For more information on how to write a good question, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 1):

add below import

```
import androidx.navigation.plusAssign
```

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamic Feature Module Support**

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.3.0-alpha06"
```

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/navigation